# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL when passing string to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following:

```
var params = httpGet("http://localhost/data");

console.log(params)
```

Which displays this in the console:

```
{
  "Success": true,
  "Data": {
    "requestBody": {
      "Text": "{\r\n  \"ID\": 1,\r\n  \"Name\": \"sample string 2\",\r\n  \"Desc\": \"sample string 3\",\r\n  \"quibble\": \"sample string 4\",\r\n  \"cobble\": 5,\r\n  \"abc\": 6,\r\n  \"Status\": \"Enabled\",\r\n  \"id\": 7\r\n}"
    }, 
    "responseBody": {
      "Text": "{\r\n  \"ID\": 1,\r\n  \"Name\": \"sample string 2\",\r\n  \"Desc\": \"sample string 3\",\r\n  \"quibble\": \"sample string 4\",\r\n  \"cobble\": 5,\r\n  \"abc\": 6,\r\n  \"Status\": \"Enabled\",\r\n  \"id\": 7\r\n}"
    },
    "apiDescr": "description"
  },
  "ErrorCode": 0,
  "ErrorDescription": "",
  "Meta": ""
}
```

However, when I try to pass `params` to a function like the following:

```
var params = httpGet("http://localhost/data");

console.log(params)

$(".modal-body").append("<p><a href=\"#\" role=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" onClick=\"display_params('" + params + "')\">" + key + "</a>" + " " + d.verbDocDict[key]["document"] + "</p>")
$(".modal-body").append("<div id=\"" + key + "\"></div>")

function display_params(params) {
    console.log(params)
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

**Edit**

Can people voting to close please explain how this is off-topic so I can remedy it?

httpGet:

```
function httpGet(theUrl) {
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, false);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

Comment: The carriage return/lf's are likely the issue.  Why are those in there?  I'd suggest scrubbing your source data.

Comment: It's part of an automatically generated string returned from the server. If possible, I would like to preserve them

Comment: [Can't reproduce the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/hevk2ghv/)

Comment: Are you 100% sure the problem has anything to do `display_params` and not to do possibly with building strings with unescaped quotes? Also, can you show the source of `httpGet`?

Comment: Oh building the string with unescaped quotes makes sense, updated question with httpGet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using the `escape` and `unescape` functions:

```
var params = httpGet("http://localhost/data");

$(".modal-body").append("<p><a href=\"#\" role=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" onClick=\"display_params('" + escape(params) + "')\">" + key + "</a>" + " " + d.verbDocDict[key]["document"] + "</p>")
$(".modal-body").append("<div id=\"" + key + "\"></div>")

function display_params(params) {
    console.log(unescape(params))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing quotes:

```
var params = httpGet("http://localhost/data);
```

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo on my part